# Finding permutations of 3 types of instance that cannot appear as a block

Tags: combinatorics

There are 3 types of cars, there are 6 blue cars, 7 pink cars, 8 white cars.

What is the number of permutations that those cars can be sorted in a parking lot where you cannot have all the cars from the same colour appear as a block.

e.g:

```
*,b,b,b,b,b,b,* <-- invalid
*,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,* <-- invalid
*,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,* <-- invalid
b,b,b,b,b,p,p,p,p,p,p,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,b,p,w <-- valid
```

I was thinking of doing it on the negative and maybe "combining" blocks of each type as one, and then dividing the solution to 3 ways, but the more I got into thinking the more complex it got.

Comment: Are cars of the same color considered to be distinct or indistinguishable?

Comment: The cars are all different.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to calculate total no. of ways to arrange them all, no. of ways where cars of one/two/three color(s) are together and try to use Inclusion-Exclusion principle